# How can I get the position of TScrollBox in TLayout while panning?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using a parent FMX.Layouts.TScrollBox to zoom and pan through a child TLayout. Once the TLayout gets bigger than the TScrollBox, panning is possible.

I'd like the (top left) position of the TScrollBox [image: (image)].

Looking through both TScrollBox & TLayout properties I cannot find a position that works for me (tried many). There's other ways to do it, but it seems standard to me and should(?) be included in the base class.

PS: For panning I use TScrollBox.AniCalculations but I don't think that matters/helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the position use the `ViewportPosition` property of the `TScrollBox`. It's a `TPointF` and is described as:

> Coordinates of the origin of the scrolling viewport specified as the offset from the origin of the content layout of this scroll box.

It is [documented here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Layouts.TCustomScrollBox.ViewportPosition)

If you need an event during panning, use the `OnViewportPositionChange()` event of type `TPositionChangeEvent()` 
It is not properly documented but is declared as:

```
TPositionChangeEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject;
                         const OldViewportPosition, NewViewportPosition: TPointF;
                         const ContentSizeChanged: Boolean) of object;
```

Should be quite self explanatory

alternatively `OnHScrollChange()` and/or `OnVScrollChange()` of type `TNotifyEvent`

Comment: How come they don't have a ViewportSize (and related change event) at TCustomScrollBox? I see one in TPresentedScrollBox only. Wonder if I can get that via ContentLayout.Size (I suppose Content.Size will give the size of the whole content, not the visible viewport size)